# WCF Rest Serialization- Response serializes 2 times?

Tags: rest, wcf, serialization

I have one question. I am using WCF Rest service. As WCF rest service is using default serializer. So I want to use newtonsoft. As newtonsoft is fast compare to .net serializer.

So before sending response to client  I am serializing using

```
string responseJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstOrder);
return responseJson;
```

my questions are

1. Does .net run-time serialize the responseJson string again while sending response to client ?

if yes then data is serializing two times. how can avoid this ?

2. Is best way to send always string content back to client instead of generic list ?

my client is angular 4

Please give me suggestions.

Comment: What makes you think the runtime is serializing it twice?

Comment: Hello Tim, I mean first my self serializing using newtonsoft and again serializing by runtime(IIS) using datacontract serializer while sending response back.